# Proxy to collect Domain addresses

Tags: proxy, firewall, proxy-server

Our company IT is requesting a list of domain's we regularly visit to allow them through the newly installed firewall (insanely stupid, I know).  Is there a Proxy server which Can sift through the stuff I visit regularly and compile a list?

Answer (score 0):

There's the Squid caching proxy server which can be configured to restrict users to certain IDNs (Internet Domain Names) specifically (e.g., only example.com and NOT www.example.com) or with any number of additional levels (e.g., example.com and everything else that ends with .example.com).  The lists of these IDNs is a plain/text file that you can modify easily at any time.

As for the contents of the IDN list, you'll need to figure out how to do this on your own since the histories tend to be a proprietary format.

If you're one of those users who needs to have unrestricted access to internet sites (e.g., because your job requires you to do research online), then the proxy server can also be configured to exclude you from, or not include you in, the list of restricted users.